# How to set resize Icons(16x16/32x32/80x80) dynamically in the PowerPoint Add-In control Ribbon button

Tags: c#, vsto, powerpoint

I created an add-in over PowerPoint and ran into a problem. I've created buttons and put images in there that don't look good. That's because I'm exhibiting a single 32x32 image.

How do I get my PowerPoint Add-in to dynamically proportion an image ( 16x16/32x32/80x80 ) in a button?

Thanks in advance for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I would set this in the customUI XML **group attributes** rather than code it:

```
autoscale = "True"
```

Then the icons change size as the program window is resized.

Using **SizeDefinitions** and **ScalingPolicy**, you can get more control over the icon arrangements and sizes. [Customizing a Ribbon Through Size Definitions and Scaling Policies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/windowsribbon/windowsribbon-templates)

If there's a reson you need to resize through code, please include more information in your question about your requirements.

Comment: Hi, @john
I open in VS 2017 (C#) file **Test_tab.cs[Design]** and click left button -> Export Ribbon to XML.I don't really understand how to set the settings you described (maybe because c++).
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<customUI onLoad="Ribbon_Load" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2006/01/customui">
<ribbon>
<tabs>
<tab idMso="TabAddIns" label="FFF TAB">
<group id="group_logo">
<button id="fff_logotype" onAction="fff_logotype_Click" label="GGGGG" size="large" />
</group>
</tab>
</tabs>
</ribbon>
</customUI>`

Comment: To autoscale a group, change <group id="group_logo"> to <group id="group_logo" autoscale="true">